# Cancelling USPS mail forwarding

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if this question or some obvious adaptation belongs on law.stackexchange.com, so I'm asking here.

Late last year I started a job that I thought would be a good fit, but it didn't pan out. When I moved to start the job, I got items in the mail intended for others at the same basic address.

After I returned, I asked the representative at the post office if I could have the forwarding canceled. She told me to add another forwarding request, from the other address to where I returned.

I did what I was told to, and now people are getting letters bounced.

I would like proper mail delivery such as I had before moving for that job, and I envision that would happen if a postmaster or other employee of sufficient rank would delete or deactivate the original forwarding address.

What options will I have that will produce results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a legal question here, but one of how to find a way to get the Post Office to provide you better customer service.